# MongoDB merge $facet results with corresponding items

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hello I have a collection like this

```
"_id"  :"601bd0f4be72d839303adcd3",
"title":"Payment-1",
"initialBalance": {"$numberDecimal": "75"},
"paymentHistory":[
  {"_id": "601bd1542df40f2ca8a769df","payment": {"$numberDecimal": "10"}},
  {"_id": "601bd1542df40f2ca8a769de","payment": {"$numberDecimal": "20"}},
]
```

**I want to calculate active balance (initialBalance - total of paymentHistory) for each payment.**

I calculated total payments from **paymentHistory** for each document in collection.

```
this.aggregate([
  {$match:{...}},
  {
    $facet:{
      info:[
        {$project:{_id:1,title:1,initialBalance:1}}
      ],
      subPayments:[
        {$unwind:"$paymentHistory"},
        {$group:{_id:"$_id",total:{$sum:"$paymentHistory.payment"}}},
      ]
    }
   }
])
```

I get this result for above query.

```
 "info": [
            {
                "_id": "601bd0f4be72d839303adcd3",  
                "title": "Payment-1",
                "initialBalance": {"$numberDecimal": "580"},
            },
            ...
         ],
  "subPayments": [
            {
                "_id": "601bd0f4be72d839303adcd3",
                "total": {"$numberDecimal": "80.75"}
            },
            ...
        ]
```

I added following lines to aggregation.

```
  {$facet:{...}},
  {$project: {payments:{$setUnion:['$info','$subPayments']}}},
  {$unwind: '$payments'},
  {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$payments" }},
```

Now, I get this result

```
{
    "_id": "601bd0f4be72d839303adcd3",
    "total": {"$numberDecimal": "80.75"}
},
{
    "_id": "601bd0f4be72d839303adcd3",
    "title": "Payment-1",
    "initialBalance": {"$numberDecimal": "580"},
},
{...}
```

I think if I group them via _id, then I calculate activeBalance in $project aggregation.

```
...
{
  $group:{
      _id:"$_id",
      title:{$first:"$title"},
      initialBalance:{$first:"$initialBalance"},
      totalPayment:{$first: "$total"},
    }
},
{
  $set:{activeBalance:{$subtract:[{$ifNull:["$initialBalance",0]}, {$ifNull:["$totalPayment",0]}]}}
}
```

The problem is after $group aggregation fields return null.

```
 {
        "_id": "601bd0f4be72d839303adcd3",
        "title": null,
        "initialBalance": null,
        "totalPayment": {
            "$numberDecimal": "80.75"
        },
        "activeBalance": {
            "$numberDecimal": "-80.75"
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest instead of facets, use `$reduce` to get the sum of `paymentHistory`. This way, you will have one document per _id with sum and initialBalance from which to do a simple subtraction calculation. The approach you are using right now looks little complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what @prasad_ suggested:

```js
db.accounts.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      activeBalance: {
        $subtract: [
          "$initialBalance",
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$paymentHistory",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: { $sum: ["$$value", "$$this.payment"] }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```